# Angular image on load with cache

Tags: angularjs, caching, onload

There are so many answers for question how can we check when image get loaded. In my case, some of the images are cached and script:

```
        element.bind('load', function () {
            // fire something
        });
```

is not working. It's work perfectly when image is not cached, but when it's cached it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If image is saved in browser cache, img.onload event will be not called.

I googled for the problem and this is a general problem with vanilla js and there are only workarounds for this.

The best workaround in my opinion is this :

Set the `onload` property before the `src`.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
   alert("image is loaded");
}
img.src = "img.jpg";
```

So I guess you will have to reset the src attributes of the images after you declare element.bind listener.

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply earlier, that didn't worked out for me.